# jQuery scroll down only the elements inside a DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

There is a `DIV` in my website and it is the css

```
div{
max-height:400px;
overflow:auto;
}
```

I'm going to create a button to scroll down only the elements inside this `DIV` to a certain position not the whole page. I mean I want to scroll down the `DIV`. I know how to do this for the whole page as this was asked before but I don't know how do this for a `DIV`.

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/aamir/cYwM8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In  plain vanilla Javascript you can simply do:

`document.getElementById('yourDiv').scrollTop = *position*;`

Where *position* is the scroll position you wish to set.

If you want to scroll the `div` to the top of another element within it, you can use e.g.:

```
document.getElementById('yourDiv').scrollTop = document.getElementById('scrollToElement').offsetTop;
```

If you want to use jQuery, you can nicely animate the scroll- using:

```
$("yourDiv").animate({scrollTop:*position*}, '500', 'swing', function() { 
   // anything to do after scroll
});
```

Comment: How do I findout what the `position` must be? there are set of elements called `#elemet1`, `#element2` and so on. if I want to scroll down until the `#element2` comes at the top of the `DIV`, how do I find the `#element2` distance from the top of the `DIV`?